# How to use sed to replace a line with equal sign and whitespace?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

One file contains one line '   instances       = 50', I want to replace it to '   instances       = 300';

I was trying to do it by `sed 's/instances       = 50/instances        = 300/g' /etc/xinetd.conf`.

But it failed. How to implement it?thanks.

Comment: What was the issue? You probably need to use the `-i` option to make the changes to the file instead of printing to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be your space actually see the tab character

```
[root@cAdmin tmp]# more a
instances       = 50
instances       = 50
[root@cAdmin tmp]# sed 's/instances       = 50/instances       = 300/' a  
instances       = 300
instances       = 50
[root@cAdmin tmp]# sed 's/\(instances[^0-9]*\)50/\1300/' a  
instances       = 300
instances       = 300
```

Comment: You can man sed `the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to  the corresponding  matching  sub-expressions in the regexp`